# Nonlinear navigation via mvvmcross

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm, mvvmcross

Just started playing with MvvmCross. Just wondering, if it can handle nonlinear navigation?

```
MainPage -> SelectStore -> SelectItems -> SelectSlot -> ConfirmOrder -> (!) MainPage
```

In my previous project, i used MvvmLight and [NonLinearNaviService](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Solving_Circular_Navigation_in_Silverlight_for_Window_Phone) (i'm not too satisfied with it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent to a NavigationService in MvvmCross is a `Presenter`.

You can easily provide your own custom presenters - and you can code these on each platform to provide non-linear paths.

For most of the platforms this is straight-forward - but for Android, it can be a little more tricky - mainly because the Android Activity back stack is not as straight-forward to manipulate as Windows Pages and as iOS NavigationControllers

Comment: Ok, thanks for punching into the right direction. So, does that mean that "native" way of navigation is "deprecated" (there's no navigation between pages, if to talk about WP), only "one page" is shown and it "renders" different Presenters?

Comment: Here are some examples http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/presenter-roundup.html

Answer (score 1):

You can navigate to whatever ViewModel you want, by calling **ShowViewModel** from MvxViewModel context.

You can also navigate to ViewModel outside the MvxViewModel context - from any part of your application using:

```
Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewDispatcher>().ShowViewModel(.....).
```

If you want to pop ViewModel from stack you can use:

```
// Remove current page from BackStack
var entry= Frame.BackStack.Last(entry => entry.SourcePageType == this.GetType());
Frame.BackStack.Remove(entry);
            //Or
Frame.BackStack.RemoveAt(Frame.BackStack.Count - 1);
```

Comment: True, but what about backstack? In my case, if you'd come to MainPage at the end of the list and press a Back key, you'd return to ConfirmOrder page, which is not cool.